# Adding event listener to an image KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, event-listener

I would like to add an event listener to my image object so that when clicked it destroys itself but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
var tshirtS = new Image();
tshirtS.onload = function () {
    var tshirtSk = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: tshirtS,
        width: 50,
        height: 58,
        listening: true
    });

    tshirtS.on('click', function() {
        tshirtS.destroy();
  });

    // add the image to the layer
    layer2.add(tshirtSk);
    typeOptions.add(tshirtSk);

    stage.add(layer2);
    typeOptions.draw();
    return tshirtSk;
};
tshirtS.src = 'tshirt-small.png';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of glitches in your code:

- tshirtSk is the object you should assign the click event to
- after you destroy the tshirtSk, you must redraw the layer to un-display tshirtSk

Fixed code:

```
// not tshirtS.on('click',function(){

tshirtSk.on('click', function() {
    tshirtSk.destroy();
    layer2.draw();
});
```

Good luck with your project!

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DcjnF/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer2);

    var tshirtS = new Image();
    tshirtS.onload = function () {
        var tshirtSk = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: tshirtS,
            width: 50,
            height: 58,
            listening: true
        });
        //
        tshirtSk.on('click', function() {
            tshirtSk.destroy();
            layer2.draw();
        });
        // add the image to the layer
        layer2.add(tshirtSk);
        layer2.draw();
        return tshirtSk;
    };
    tshirtS.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/T-Shirt_blue.png';


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h4>Click to destroy the T-shirt.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Addition: add image on stage click ]**

You can listen for clicks on tshirtSk and add a new image like this:

```
tshirtSk.on('click', function (event) {
    layer2.add(new Kinetic.Image({image:yourOtherImage}));
    layer2.draw();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This works however now the image is not part of the typeOptions group. Also sorry to be cheeky but can you tell me how I would go about drawing a new image on click?

Comment: yourObject.destroy() completely destroys yourObject so it can't be part of a group any more--it no longer exsits.  If you want yourObject to simply be removed from the group (but not destroyed) you can do yourObject.remove(). That way you can later put yourObject back into the group with group.add(yourObject).  I added to my answer to show how to add an image upon a click.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself very well, what I meant was when I click on tshirtSk, it draws another image.

Comment: Hmmm...you're already using tshirtSk's click event to remove it.  Anyway, I edited my additional answer so instead `yourOtherImage` is added when tshirtSk is clicked.